# Is this proposition incomplete?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In mendelson logic textbook , there is this proposition,(I will replace some letters to make it easier to read)

*"If $P$ is a tautology containing as statement letters $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ and $Q$ arises from $T$ by substituting statement forms $B_1,B_2,...,B_n$ for $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ ,respectively, then $Q$ is a tautology;that is ,substituting in a tautology yields a tautology"*

For me , this seems incomplete.Shouldn't there be this line also that ,*"$A_1 \equiv B_1 , A_2 \equiv B_2 , ... , A_n \equiv B_n$* "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mauro showed: No, this is not necessary.

In fact, the fact that the $B_i$'s need not be equivalent to the $A_i$'s reveals the real 'power' of this proposition. It shows that once you know that a certain statement is a tautology, then anything with that same abstract 'form' will be a tautology as well. And, since the $A_i$'s are statement letters, it doesn't matter what you substitute them with: the abstract form will be retained, and hence the result is still a tautology.

To illustrate this with Mauro's example: we know that $p \lor \neg p$ is a tautology, and indeed anything of the form $[something] \lor \neg [something]$. So, no matter what $[something]$ you substitute for $p$, the result is a tautology.

And finally, to demonstrate the importance that we are subsitutiong statements for statemwnt *letters*, note that $p \lor \neg p$ could also be seen as being if the form $[some statement]$, as of course *every* statement is ... but clearly just substituting justanything  for $p \lor \neg p$ as a whole does not mean we end up with a tautology.

And if that latter example is a bit too abstract for you:

Consider the statement $(p \lor \neg p) \land (q \to q)$

This is a tautology, as of course anything of the form $[something1] \lor [something1] \land ([something2] \to [something2])$ is. This is why you can systematically substitute *anything* for $p$ and $q$ and still have a tautology.

However, this statement is also of the form $[something1] \land [something2]$. But that is *not* a tautologous form: $r \land s$ is not a tautology. Hence, substituting just anything for the complex statements $p \lor \neg p $ and for $q \to q$ does not necessarily result in a tautology. It is only when you work with the atomic variables that you can be guaranteed to retain 'tautologousness'.

Comment: Then is there a rigorous proof of this proposition or is it too obvious to be proven? [To me  this proposition seems to be too obvious]

Comment: @Prithubiswas Yes, there is a rigorous proof for this. Look for 'Substitution Theorem' or 'Replacement Theorem'... although please keep in mind that there are two main such theorems: one is the one we are dealing with here, but another one is the one that I think you had in mind when you posted your question:  that as long as two expressions *are* equivalent, then we can substitute the one for the other one in a larger expression and have the result be equivalent to the original - so that latter is the one you rely on when you're doing Boolean algebra (DeMorgan, Distribution, etc)

Answer (score 0):

No.

$p \lor \lnot p$ is a tautology. According to the proposition, also $(p \lor q) \lor \lnot (p \lor q)$ is.

But $p$ and $p \lor q$ are not equivalent.